# How to call decode function on column before insert statement?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table and some of the columns are "bytea" type. What I want to do is; Before any insert statement check if a column type is "bytea" then decode hex value of column value.

Is there a way to create a trigger function like below?

```
INSERT INTO USERS (ID, NAME, STATUS) VALUES ('0x3BEDDASTSFSFSDS', 'test', 'new')
```

to

```
INSERT INTO USERS (ID, NAME, STATUS) VALUES (decode('0x3BEDDASTSFSFSDS', 'hex'), 'test', 'new')
```

Comment: Your string isn't a valid hexadecimal representation, at least when using the usual digits "0" to "F". There's "S" and "T" in yours. As for your question, I think the value has already been implicitly casted when a trigger sees it, so I guess there's no way to get the type of the original expression in the `INSERT` statement there and what you want to do maybe is a no can do. Leaving aside, that it also seems a little odd. Convert the value where you know what it is and how it needs to be converted, that is in the `INSERT` statement instead of throwing guesses under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to intercept the input string before Postgres parses it as a `bytea`.

It'll be read as an ["escape" format literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html#id-1.5.7.12.10), i.e. the `bytea` will end up holding the hex digits' ASCII codepoints. You can undo this, though it's a little unpleasant:

```
create function trg() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
  assert substring(new.id from 1 for 2) = '0x';
  new.id = decode(convert_from(substring(new.id from 3), current_setting('server_encoding')), 'hex');
  return new;
end
$$;

create trigger trg
before insert on users
for each row
execute procedure trg();
```

If you have any control over the input, just change the `0x` to `\x`, and Postgres will convert it for you.